# User Structure, Multiple User Types

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-applications, data-structures

I am currently developing a new database / web application for our school. I will need to supply a little bit of background information to make my question a little more relatable.

There are many different user types that will access this application each needing to access different parts of the application with different permissions for each “zone” they may be able to access.

For example:

A student can login and access there information and update their details as well as download copies of their reports (so they can only see their information)

A teacher can login and access there information and all the students they teach

A manager can login and access there information and all the teachers and students they manage

There are then a bunch of other login types however for this question they are not really important as they are all technically just more users which do not have or require their own table for extra information.

I have for the most part decided on a structure that I am happy with, however I keep changing my mind on how I think the following is best done.

I have a user table (User_T) where all the relevant user information is stored, (username, password, etc.)

However I also have separate tables for some of the user types (EG, Student, Staff, ETC), this is necessary because a student needs to have different information stored than a staff member.
Here is where my problem lies, all of the users will have some of the same basic fields (First name, Last name, Birthdate, Gender, etc.).

Should I store these in the User_T table? Or in the individual tables?

If I store them all in the User_T table this makes it easier to have the application pull their information and allow them to update, on the down side when displaying student details for example, I will need to reference the User_T to get the students name etc.

I am currently in the mindset that the best option is to have the separate tables with all the fields and join them in a view User_V, with a field that indicates the origin of the data so that when an update is preformed it can be applied against the appropriate table.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can an individual be in more than one role, e.g. could an administrative assistant take a class?

Comment: Are there any other restrictions on scope.  For example, are an instructor's actions limited to the department they are in, or to the students in their classes?

Comment: yes an individiaul could be in more than one role, for example, you could be teacher, and a manager, or even a payroll officer, and not only do you need access to different pages, you need different access with in the pages (example: payroll officer can add payroll recrods, manager cannot, but can view records), there are also restrictions on scope, for example an instructor may be in the german depeartment, but may only be able to see or action students they teacher, aswell as a admin officer may only be able to see students for there area etc

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there would be good separation by using the User_T table as the general "people" profile table and the other tables for the unique role specific data. User_T would store the more general info about the person and the ID in this table would be perhaps a Foreign Key called "person_id" in the other tables.

Going with this table schema would also depend on how often you might query this shared general data together. For example, if you plan to search a name or email without knowing the type/role (whether staff, student, etc), then it is good to have this general people information in the User_T table apart from the other information. If you knew the role/type, you could choose the corresponding table to search in and simply JOIN as needed for the User_T data. But if you don't separate your tables this way, then you are left with using a VIEW or UNION to allow you to search on only those general columns with a single query, which in my opinion is much more troublesome to optimize.

```
    User_T table: id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, birthdate, role, ...
    Students table: id, person_id, gpa, ...
    Staff table: id, person_id, staff_type, hire_date, ...
```

Comment: the data will be queried a lot, we have more than 16,000 students and 900 teachers, as the receptionists are constantly looking up student records (in regards to calls), i can only assume there would be alot more querying than users logging on. however, with this said duiring report writing time, all 900+ teachers are logging in to write reports, and their name etc, is accessed for this process (in both tables in old system and this cuases major headaches), load has never really been an issue for us, everything is fairly optimized and we have a decent backend,

Comment: but I would still like to do this the right way, instead of the easy way... just not sure what the "right" way is... let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: also the other problem is, that when a student completes there study, do they stay in the user table? as we are required by law to keep there details for 7 years, the user table could get very large.